# Extensive travel history but unemployed. Will I get a schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, schengen-visas, nigerian-citizens

I'm 25 years old, single, Nigerian and currently unemployed. I've been issued many schengen, US and UK visas before and travelled to visit family who are German citizens. My previous visa was multiple entry for 2 years.

I'm applying for one this week to visit family again and i'm worried I may be refused since i'm no longer a student and not a graduate either. My mother is sponsoring me and I have evidence to support that including a bank statement. I also have a formal declaration from my uncle as usual stating i'm his niece and coming to visit him. What are my chances?

I'm worried they'll say I don't have sufficient ties to my home country.

Comment: There’s veey little justification for giving you a visa if the consular officer follows normal procedures.

Comment: @samian You’ve unfortunately lost your previous tie and haven’t yet acquired one to replace it. If I were you I would not risk a refusal to blemish your otherwise impeccable travel history unless you have a much stronger premise than ‘just visiting’ to demonstrate that it is absolutely essential for you to make this trip. Even then, I’d think twice.

Comment: Adding on from the 2 comments, if I were you I'd at least get stable employment before you think about applying again.